# Cannot Push values of one array into another in Angular pipes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to store the values of items[] array in the ResultSet[]. I have tried many ways to store the values but i am not able to it. Below is my code for Pipe.

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { Bus } from '/home/pavan/Desktop/Pavan/apstrtcAngular/src/app/Bus';
    import { Item } from './Item';
    @Pipe({
      name: 'boardingFilter'
    })
    export class BoardingFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(items: Bus[], customfilter1: Item[]): Bus[] {
    let ResultSet: Bus[];
        if (!items || !customfilter1) {
          return items;
        }
        else if (customfilter1.length == 0) {
          return items;
        }
        else{
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < customfilter1.length; j++) {
            if (customfilter1[j].item_text === items[i].boardingpoint) {
              ResultSet.push(items[i]);
              console.log("Result Set =" + ResultSet);
            }
          }
        }
        return ResultSet;
      }
    }
}
```

Below is the Bus class and the Item class

```
    export class Bus {
    serviceno: String;
    board: String;
    destination: String;
    duration: string;
    type: string;
    price: string;
    bustype: string;
    boardingpoint: string;
    droppingpoint:string
  }
```

The Item Class is

```
export class Item {
    item_id: string;
    item_text:string;
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you able to create a StackBlitz demo that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: The error is displayed in the browsers console as, ERROR TypeError: "ResultSet is undefined"

Comment: You need to initialise your ResultSet then. `let ResultSet: Bus[] = [];`

Comment: Thank you, its working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe